# Extract Formula (text) field while referencing an existing saved search using NetSuite WebServices

Tags: web-services, netsuite

I am trying to extract NetSuite saved search results using webservices. In the response I am only seeing the normal fields(entered in the Results section) but not the Formula (Text) field.

Below is the image of the saved search results section.

[image: Saved search results section with Formula (Text)]

Below is the request sent to NetSuite.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tns="urn:platform_2014_2.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
<soap:Header>
    <urn5:preferences xmlns:urn5="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <urn6:warningAsError xmlns:urn6="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">false</urn6:warningAsError>
        <urn7:disableMandatoryCustomFieldValidation xmlns:urn7="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">false</urn7:disableMandatoryCustomFieldValidation>
        <urn7:ignoreReadOnlyFields xmlns:urn7="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">false</urn7:ignoreReadOnlyFields>
    </urn5:preferences>
    <urn8:searchPreferences xmlns:urn8="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <urn9:bodyFieldsOnly xmlns:urn9="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">true</urn9:bodyFieldsOnly>
        <urn10:pageSize xmlns:urn10="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">1000</urn10:pageSize>
        <urn11:returnSearchColumns xmlns:urn11="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">true</urn11:returnSearchColumns>
    </urn8:searchPreferences>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <platformMsgs:search xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformMsgs:searchRecord xsi:type="ns1:CustomerSearchAdvanced" xmlns:ns1="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" savedSearchId="2469"/>
    </platformMsgs:search>
</soap:Body>
```

The response I am seeing is below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <platformMsgs:documentInfo 
        xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_TSTDRV840553_091920161097968934683523704_57aaf0b</platformMsgs:nsId>
    </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <searchResponse 
        xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <platformCore:searchResult 
            xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformCore:status isSuccess="true"/>
            <platformCore:totalRecords>2</platformCore:totalRecords>
            <platformCore:pageSize>1000</platformCore:pageSize>
            <platformCore:totalPages>1</platformCore:totalPages>
            <platformCore:pageIndex>1</platformCore:pageIndex>
            <platformCore:searchId>WEBSERVICES_TSTDRV840553_091920161097968934683523704_57aaf0b</platformCore:searchId>
            <platformCore:searchRowList>
                <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="listRel:CustomerSearchRow" 
                    xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <listRel:basic 
                        xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                        <platformCommon:comments>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>test</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:comments>
                        <platformCommon:entityId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>test c 97161</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:entityId>
                        <platformCommon:entityStatus>
                            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="13"/>
                        </platformCommon:entityStatus>
                        <platformCommon:internalId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="59951"/>
                        </platformCommon:internalId>
                    </listRel:basic>
                </platformCore:searchRow>
                <platformCore:searchRow xsi:type="listRel:CustomerSearchRow" 
                    xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2014_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <listRel:basic 
                        xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                        <platformCommon:comments>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>test</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:comments>
                        <platformCommon:entityId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue>test c 97162</platformCore:searchValue>
                        </platformCommon:entityId>
                        <platformCommon:entityStatus>
                            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="13"/>
                        </platformCommon:entityStatus>
                        <platformCommon:internalId>
                            <platformCore:searchValue internalId="59952"/>
                        </platformCommon:internalId>
                    </listRel:basic>
                </platformCore:searchRow>
            </platformCore:searchRowList>
        </platformCore:searchResult>
    </searchResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I don't see any explanation/examples related to this in NetSuite help guide as well.

Is there any other way that we need to trigger the request for extracting formula fields? Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this same topic and I don't believe Web Services supports formula fields in the result set. There appears to be no mechanism for returning them in a statically defined SOAP response. In my case, I needed the following formula.

`GREATEST({trandate},{lastmodifieddate},{linelastmodifieddate},{billingtransaction.trandate},{billingtransaction.lastmodifieddate},{billingtransaction.linelastmodifieddate})`

It existed in my saved search and did not throw an error when referenced from SuiteTalk. However, the formula field was not present as a column in my result set. I had to include each individual field used in my formula in the saved search and then recreate the formula in code.

If you need to use a formula as part of your filter criteria (to apply to a saved search), it will need to be defined in the saved search itself. You will not be able to apply formula based filters via the SuiteTalk API.

```
TransactionSearchAdvanced customSearch = new TransactionSearchAdvanced()
{
    savedSearchScriptId = "customsearch_[Your ID here]"
    ,
    criteria = new TransactionSearch()
    {
        [Formula fields are NOT supported here]
    }

};
```